# Undefined function or variable 'skript_name' Matlab

Tags: matlab, classification, accelerometer

I'm using an open source code from **Matlab**: http://makerzone.mathworks.com/uncategorized/activity-detection-with-matlab/

for activity detection. All data that I need is in the zip file that you can download above. When I try to run the main script activityDetection.m that classificate the data it shows this error: **Undefined function or variable 'activityDetection'.**

maybe knows someone how to fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded zip file and then run it on my laptop. It works just fine.

You need to change your working directory to the directory where the code is (or add the directory to your MATLAB path by typing `addpath('ADRESS TO DIRECTORY')`).